# Highcharts with Ajax call returning JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, highcharts

I am trying to use Highcharts with an external server that returns a JSON file but I cannot get the returning file to bind to the chart. I am developing the application in ASP.NET MVC

My attempt at the code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/Q6ngj/2/

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: urlM4AirTemp,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    cache: true,
    jsonp: false,
    jsonpCallback: 'ourCallbackM4AirTemp'}).done(function (airTempData) {

        var msg = airTempData.table.rows;
        var intYr;
        var intMonth;
        var intDay;
        var intHour;
        var intMin;
        var intSec;
        jQuery.each(msg,function(i,value){
        intYr = value[0].substring(0,4);
        intMonth = value[0].substring(5,7)-1;
        intDay = value[0].substring(8,10);
        intHour = value[0].substring(11,13);
        intMin = value[0].substring(14,16);
        intSec = value[0].substring(17,19);
        var d = new Date(intYr,intMonth,intDay, intHour,intMin, intSec);
        d =d.toUTCString();

        d=Date.parse(d);
        airTemp.push([d,value[1]]);
        }); 

    //Load up Graph
    options.series[0].data = airTemp;

    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
};
```

Is ajax the correct method to call here or should I be using getJSON?

Answer (score 1):

In first line (script at jsfiddle):

```
(function(){
```

In last:

```
})();
```

And whole json in remote file should be wrapped in `ourCallbackM4AirTemp(` and `);` .

Comment: Made the suggested edits to the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Q6ngj/5/ but the chart is still not rendering?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Q6ngj/6/ - 22 line was wrong, but still remote file with data is not jsonP! If file `http://erddap.marine.ie/erddap/tabledap/IMI-WaveBuoyForecast.json?time,significant_wave_height&time%3E=2013-08-14T00:00:00Z&stationID=%22M6%22` isn't yours - you have to get it using proxy and then wrap with `ourCallbackM4AirTemp(` and `);`

Answer (score 0):

Two problems I see in jsFiddle:

- `jsonpCallback: ('ourCallbackM4AirTemp');` -> remove `;`, it breaks js code
- your JSONP is simple JSON, so it won't work, read about differences between JSON ans JSONP

Comment: Would using 'getJson' be a better approach, similar to the example given here http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/getting-data-across-domains-jsonp ?

Comment: DaveMc, this is exactly what I'm talking about.

Comment: Oh, right. Haven't seen that part in @Krzysiek answer. It's exaclty what is written in tutorial by Highcharts.